# Books on locally convex topological vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, topological-vector-spaces, book-recommendation, locally-convex-spaces

My friend asked me for a good book about locally convex topological vector space. I'm  not familar with this. Could you give me some good references on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I admit I have a weakness for Rudin's *Functional Analysis* myself. Some people find Rudin's books *too* polished, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "polished"?

Comment: “Polished” means the proofs are elegantly minimal. *Too* polished would mean they are so elegantly minimal that the idea which makes it work is lost, or at least hard to see. And it leaves you scratching your head, wondering how the author of the proof came up with that in the first place.

Comment: It seems to me that it's flawed that Rudin uses little categorical language, and maybe viewpoint.

Answer (score 4):

A very nice book is also "Topological vector spaces, distributions and kernels" by F. Trèves.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tome of Bourbaki on Topological Vector Spaces, it is always a good reference.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite long chapters devoted to locally convex tvs's in *[Topological Vector Spaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387987266)* by H.H. Schaefer and in *Topological Vector Spaces* by A. Grothendieck.

Answer (score 1):

A more recent book which is very good, especially for beginners in the theory, is ["Locally Convex Spaces"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319020440) by M. S. Osborne. Another very good introductory book is ["Introduction to Functional Analysis"](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/introduction-to-functional-analysis-9780198514855?prevSortField=1&sortField=1&resultsPerPage=20&start=180&lang=en&cc=us#) by Meise and Vogt.